# Record is not visible in database but available in front end application

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Some records are displayed in front end but not available for SQL select query. This is happening only for few records rest all are displayed in query.

What could be the cause and how to get it displayed?

Comment: Have the affected records just been added by the front-end session, and are only visible to that session? If so, is the application committing the data it added? If not are you sure you're looking at the same database/schema?

Comment: Thats added 1 yr back....schema/database is same...

Comment: Then you'd need to at least show how the data is appearing and how you're attempting to query it, and if it can be found with `like`. You're probably just querying it slightly wrong; wrong case, or the data has leading or trailing whitespace that isn't obvious, or even a character mistake (mixing zero with capital O, say). Impossible to tell from what you've said.

Comment: Certainly if you were talking about Oracle Apps, fine grain access control (aka virtual private database) is used pervasively.  This type of access control uses application context and security policies (see here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG98216).